# Substituting string in a file by another string with leading zeros in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file `filename` for which I want to substitute a certain numerical string in row `row_num`by another one that starts with leading zeros. That row is:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f1515"
```

And I would like to substitute the last four digits so that **the desired end result is**:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f0155"
```

The command I am using is:

```
gawk  'NR=='$row_num'{gsub(/'1515'/,'0155')};1' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```

The problem is that linux interprets 0155 as an octal number due to the leading zero and returns:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f109"
```

Resolving the interpretation by adding `10#` to `0155` does not resolve my issue because then it is evaluated and the zero is avoided, yielding:

```
"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f155"
```

**How can I make the substitution so that I obtain the desired output?**

I would like the solution to be general so that it also works in the case where the first element is nonzero, for which my provided solution does work.

Comment: The internal single-quotes may not be doing what you think they are. Use double-quotes around the second number. You don't need any quotes around the one in the regex (although you should probably anchor it)

Comment: You are right, in this example I don´t need the single quotes. However, if I want to pass 1515 as the value of a variable, i.e. val=1515, I have to use single quotes for it to work:  gawk  'NR=='$row_num'{gsub(/'$val'/,'0155')};1' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename

Comment: The second number still needs double-quotes, not single quotes. You want to treat it as a string inside awk. (It's not "linux" that is treating the number as octal, it's awk)

Comment: You are right, it worked for me like this: gawk -v row_num="$row_num" 'NR==row_num {sub(/'val'/,"'$val2'")};1' filename. I needed the double quotes in the replacement.

Comment: `sed '/"uuid": "34ba55d4-42fd-448e-862a-f1515"/s/f1515/f0155/' file` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As general practice, following the advice from the commenters, consider moving ALL external input to variables, making the script a 'constant'. It will eliminate quoting problems, and potential risk from injections of input with special characters.

```
awk -v row_num="$row_num" -v val="$val" -v "val2=$val2" 'NR==row_num {sub(val,val2)};1' filename
# OR
awk 'NR==row_num {sub(val,val2)};1' row_num="$row_num" val="$val" "val2=$val2" filename
```

For larger script, this will make it possible to place the script into 'file.awk', simplifying the quoting even further.

replace-one.awk

```
#! /bin/env awk
NR==row_num { sub(val,val2) }
{print }
```

And invoke it with

```
replace-in-line.sh row_num="$row_num" val="$val" "val2=$val2" filename
```